# What is the raw6 protocol? Where can I find info about it?

Tags: networking

Using network tools to see my running services, I saw a raw6 protocol on one of my current connections. I tried to find info about it on the internet but I couldn't find anything. Even searching rfc's. Where is this protocol defined and what is it used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically we are familiar with TCP and UDP socket. There still many more socket that are being used in network stack.

RAW6 is one of the IPv6 socket.

You may find the socket listed in `/proc/net/sockstat6`.

RAW socket allowing packet or traffic communicate in protocoless environment.

The kernel object for this located in `af_inet6.c` linux source code.

The RFC for this RAW fall under `rfc3542`.